# How is a two qubit mixed state represented in the form of Bloch vector?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

How is a two qubit mixed state represented in the form of Bloch vector?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/346715

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

This is impossible in general, because the space of two-qubit mixed states is significantly more complicated than the Bloch sphere.

**Dimension**

The space $D_N$ of all mixed states of an $N$-level quantum system has $N^2-1$ real dimensions. For a qubit $D_2$ has only three dimensions and can be readily visualized as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, for two qubits $N=2^2 = 4$ and $D_4$ is $15$-dimensional. Consequently, there is no visualization aid analogous to the Bloch sphere that allows us to imagine the full space all at once.

**Algebraic representation**

Nevertheless, we can use other techniques to study $D_4$. Algebraically, the Bloch sphere can be thought of as a map that takes a state $\rho_1 \in D_2$ to $x_{\rho_1} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$
\rho_1 = \frac{I + x_{\rho_1} \cdot \sigma_1}{2}\tag1
$$

where $\sigma_1 = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)^T$ is a $3$-vector of Pauli operators. This representation is unique because $\{I, \sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z\}$ is a basis of the real vector space of Hermitian operators in two dimensions. Similarly, we can map every two-qubit state $\rho_2\in D_4$ to a $x_{\rho_2} \in \mathbb{R}^{15}$ such that

$$
\rho_2 = \frac{I + \sqrt{3}\,x_{\rho_2} \cdot \sigma_2}{2}\tag2
$$

where

$$
\sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
I \otimes \sigma_x\\
I \otimes \sigma_y\\
I \otimes \sigma_z\\
\sigma_x \otimes I\\
\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x\\
\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_y\\
\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_z\\
\sigma_y \otimes I\\
\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_x\\
\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y\\
\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_z\\
\sigma_z \otimes I\\
\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_x\\
\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_y\\
\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is a $15$-vector of non-identity two-qubit Pauli operators and the scaling factor $\sqrt{3}$ ensures that $\|x\|_2 \le 1$ for convenience. As before, $x_{\rho_2}$ is unique for a given state $\rho_2$.

**Back to geometry**

An immediate consequence of $(2)$ that distinguishes the shape of $D_4$ from $D_2$ is that $D_4$ is not symmetric with respect to the maximally mixed state. This is a first sign that the shape of $D_4$ is more complicated than a sphere.

Even though $D_4$ cannot be visualized all at once, we can visualize various cross-sections through $D_4$. Some $3$-dimensional cross sections turn out to be balls, some are tetrahedrons and others have more complicated shapes.

See the paper ["An elementary introduction to the geometry of quantum states with pictures"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06688) or the book "Geometry of Quantum States: An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement" by Ingemar Bengtsson and Karol Życzkowski for more details.

Comment: I would also suggest the review paper published by  Ingemar Bengtsson and Karol Życzkowski "An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement: a Geometric Approach" https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0606228.pdf

Comment: In the equation mentioned above, 2∈ℝ15, should the radius be equal to the Euclidean distance in 15 dimensional space? I mean say (2 ~ r1, r2, ....r15) then the radius is (r1^2 + r2^2 + ... + r15^2)^(1/2)? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Remember that the 15-dimensional space of mixed two-qubit states is not a sphere, so the set does not have a radius in the sense that sphere does. However, the set is contained in a sphere of radius $1$. And yes, this radius is computed using the usual Euclidean distance formula $r = \|x_{\rho_2}\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dots + x_{15}^2}$.